# Can I call methods on an object represented by a string variable?

Tags: templating, variable

I tried the **attribute** twig function for this but that did not work.

Essentially, what I'd like to achieve is the following:

```
{# This string variable is a name of the object #}
{% set myForm = 'form' %}
{# I'd like to call the 'errors' method on the 'form' object #}
{% set formErrors = myForm.errors %}
```

The problem with the above code is that the *errors* method will be called on the **myForm** object instead of the **form** object.

Is there any way to achieve what I'm trying to do here?

Comment: Can you explain why you have a string that represents the object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've run into a similar situation. I was able to get things working in my situation using Twig's `_context` variable. The object I needed was available to the page, but the object name was only known as a string on the page.

I set the object on the page, by accessing it with the string I had via the `_context` object. `_context` is a Global Variable in Twig, which contains all currently defined variables on the page. This made sure that I was accessing the form object being returned to the page (not redefining the object from the database).

```
{% set submittedFormModel = (_context[entry.formField.first().handle] is defined 
                            ? _context[entry.formField.first().handle] 
                            : null) %}
```

From there, I could access the errors via Twig's `attribute` function:

```
{% set errors = attribute(submittedFormModel, 'getErrors') %}

{% for error in errors %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

Or, via the object as normal:

```
{% for error in submittedFormModel.getErrors() %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

Twig's [attribute function](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/attribute.html) allows you to set the method as a string and not the object. The object has to be an actual object, even with that function.

```
{% set object = craft.entries.order('postdate').last() %}
{% set method = 'title' %}

{{ attribute(object, method) }}
```

The only workaround I can think of is to link your object-representing string to an actual object in your template. But this makes little sense as you probably wouldn't have set it as a string to begin with, hehe. Anyways:

```
{% if string == "craft.entries.order('postdate').last()" %}
    {% set object = craft.entries.order('postdate').last() %}
{% endif %}

{{ attribute(object, method) }}
```